# Google - Normalizing between OAuth2 and OpenID2

Tags: google-oauth

I'm following the instructions here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-federated-login-api/dNvMHuzUTAU/W-bPbZ2omlAJ

The problem is I never receive `openid_id` or `sub` from the `/o/oauth2/token` endpoint. I know I'm receiving a valid access token because I use it to call `/oauth2/v3/userinfo` (and can get `sub` from there). I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am pretty certain `openid.realm` is set correctly because I get an error if it's not set correctly. Anyone have any ideas?  Is it me or is it Google?

My request (with client ID hidden):
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2F%2A.localhost.com&state=foobar&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.localhost.com%2Foauth2cb&response_type=code&client_id=123456789.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=openid+email&display=popup`

Comment: Could you add a sample of your request please?

Comment: Edited my question with a request.

Answer (score 0):

So my problem was I was not looking in the id_token.  I was assuming it would come back as a query parameter to the callback.

Comment: Yeap, the identifier info is contained in an IDToken (which is the standard way to get user info for OAuth2 authentication flows - aka, OpenID Connect flows). Good luck.